# Describing Locus of Complex points

Tags: complex-numbers

Having trouble describing locus of complex points.

Not sure how to approach these types of questions. Do I just replace $|z|$ with $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ?

The question: 
$|z+2| + |z-2| = 5$

Comment: Think of distance. You want to find point Z such that the distance from z to 2 plus the distance from z to -2 equals 5. I think this may be an ellipse with 2 and -2 as foci.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1674177.

Answer (score 1):

An ellipse can be described as the locus of points the sum of whose distances from two points (the foci) is constant.   Thus we have an ellipse with foci $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$.